# Authentication with two different tables

Tags: database, authentication, yii2

I was working with Yii1 and for the authentication a was working with a "webuser extends CWebUser and in "UserIdentify" i was testing in access Level column in admins table, and if the user isn't in this table i search the user in Users Table.

So it was very simple to use it

Now with yii2, things become very different. I don't know from where i begin.

So if someone have an idea in how to authenticate from different tables it wil be very helpful.

Regards,